# Cannot get Terpstra-Jonckheere to match between R and SAS

Tags: r, sas

I am trying to replicate some SAS code in R, and I'm having some issues with the Terpstra-Jonckheere test.

Here is my R code:

```
perc <- c(0.225,0.425,0.525,0.300,0.300,0.250,0.125,0.200,0.500,0.150,0.450,0.450,0.350,0.375,0.250,0.300,0.225,0.400,0.400,0.275,0.100,0.200,0.150,0.375)
group <- as.ordered(factor(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4)))
jonckheere.test(perc, group, alternative="increasing")
```

The result I get from this analysis is:

```
JT = 85, p-value = 0.8816
```

The SAS code I am trying to replicate is:

```
proc freq data=q.analset; 
  where group in (1,2,3,4);
  tables perc*group/jt ;
  output out=TJres JT; 
run;
```

But that outputs the following:

```
Statistic: 110.000
Z: -1.1863
One-sided Pr < Z: 0.1177
Two-sided Pr > |Z|: 0.2355
```

Where am I going wrong? I have verified that the datasets in R and SAS are exactly the same.

Comment: I tried to do it by hand (following [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonckheere%27s_trend_test)) and I found a statistic S = -46... beats me

Comment: 0.8816 + 0.1177 looks quite close to 1 (you are testing different directions), given the fact that some of your values are tied.

Comment: @MichaelM Your comment is pretty much of an answer. Do you want to make it one?